# Quick way to compute the polynomial satisfying given conditions

Tags: functions, polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^4f(x)}{x^8+1} = 3, f(-6)=37, f(-1)=2,f(2)=5, f(3)=10$$
> Then:
>
> 1. Find the value of $f'(3)$
> 2. Find the value of $$\lim_{x \to -6} \frac{f(x)-x^2-1}{3(x+6)}$$

Both of the sub-questions require finding $f(x)$, so I'll proceed to find that. According to the first limit, $f(x)$ is a fourth-degree polymial with the leading coefficient as $3$. We can rewrite $f(x)$ as:
$$f(x) = 3x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
Given four values of $f(x_i) = y_i$, substituting them gives us a system of 4 equations in $a,b,c,d$:
$$\begin{align}
f(-6) = 37 &= 1296\times3-216a+36b-6c+d \\
f(-1) = 2 &= 3-a+b-c+d \\
f(2) = 5 &= 48 + 8a+4b+2c+d \\
f(3) = 10 &= 243 + 27a + 9b + 3c + d\\
\end{align}$$

This is extremely tedious without using a calculator/computer, so **are there any easier ways to compute $f(x)$ or solve the two sub-questions**? Preferably a method that does not involve solving the given system of equations. I am aware of Lagrange interpolation, but using that for the given values gives me a third-degree polynomial, which does not satisfy the first condition.

Comment: I would suspect that there is a way to answer to the two questions without knowing $f(x)$, otherwise the two questions are totally trivial once you know $f(x)$.

Comment: The second boils down to $f'(-6)$ too, so it's the question of finding derivatives using the given conditions on $f$. I think we can find linear combinations of the equations, giving the desired values.

Comment: Consider using Lagrange interpolation for $f(x)-3x^4$ which is of third degree.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748237/let-fx-be-a-polynomial-satisfying-lim-x-to-infty-fracx4fxx81-3/3748448#3748448